# Pig on a single machine

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, etl

Imagine that i have a file with 100 MM of records, and I want to use pig to wrangle it. 
I don't have a cluster, but I still want to use PIG for productivity reasons. Could I use PIG in a single machine or it will have a poor performance?

Does Pig will simulate a MR job in a a single machine, or will use a self backend engine to execute the process?

Answer (score 2):

Surely single machine with 100MM records processing by Hadoop won't give you performance. 
For Development/Testing purpose you can use single machine with small/moderate amount of data, but not in production.
Hadoop Linearly scales it's performace as you add more number of nodes to the cluster.
Single machine also can act as a cluster.
PIG can run in 2 modes, `local` and `mapreduce`.
In local mode no hadoop daemons and hdfs.
In mapreduce, your pig script will be converted to MR Jobs and then gets executed.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for response. When running in local mode how pig executes, for example, a group operation? Does it uses "shuffle sort strategy", sorting records and then group it? Or it uses for example, a hash group by? I am asking this to know if it really has a own engine or use the same approach as hadoop.

Comment: In local mode, only 1 reducer. So group by operation results one output file. From [link](http://www.manning.com/lam/SampleCh10.pdf)   

Pig has two major components:
1 A high-level data processing language called Pig Latin .   
2 A compiler that compiles and runs your Pig Latin scriptin a choice of
evaluation mechanisms .   The main evaluation mechanism is Hadoop. Pig also
supports a local mode for development purposes., Mean it just translates the data flows into sequence of MapReduce Jobs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply again. So if I want to execute a pig jib, but I have just one node Its better not to use pig. I really would.like to use the simple and productivity pig language but in a production environment with just one machine.

Comment: Hadoop main theme is to move processing unit to the data instead of data to the processing unit. And parallel processing is core to get more performance. If you don't  bother of performance issues, you can use single machine. It's all about your requirements fulfilling.

Comment: I am thinking about in build a backend engine to PIG, capable of processing, 100MM to 500MM records in a single machine with "good" performance. The point is: I want the PIG productivity but not the overhead to use a cluster.